# Upload Images in folder and path in sql database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Hey guys , Can anyone help me out  to add images in folder and path in sql database in c sharp 2008 in windows application?

Comment: Where you have problem ?

Comment: what coding style you prefer ?

Comment: @Prakash: Can you please share some of your code where you are facing problem, so that we can see how you are trying and where you have the problem exactly?

Comment: Actually the image is getting copy to folder but the path is not inserted in database,And i do not have any idea about that.

Comment: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Uploading-Images-to-a-Database--C---Part-I/ 


Check this link may help you

Comment: Post the sample code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code you can try with this,

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    FileInfo imageInfo = new FileInfo(File1.Value.Trim());

    if (!imageInfo.Exists)
        //Show msg for "please select one image file."
      else
      {
        switch (imageInfo.Extension.ToUpper())
       {
          case ".JPG": this.UpLoadImageFile(imageInfo); break;
          case ".GIF": this.UpLoadImageFile(imageInfo); break;
          case ".BMP": this.UpLoadImageFile(imageInfo); break;
          default: //Show msg "file type error."; break;
       }
      }
    }

    private void UpLoadImageFile(FileInfo info)
    {
         SqlConnection objConn = null;
         SqlCommand objCom = null;
       try
       {
           byte[] content = new byte[info.Length];
           FileStream imagestream = info.OpenRead();
           imagestream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
           imagestream.Close();

           objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
           objCom = new SqlCommand("insert into TableName(FieldName,Picture)values(@FieldName,@Picture)", objConn);

 SqlParameter FieldNameParameter = new SqlParameter("@FieldName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
 if (this.txtFileName.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
 FieldNameParameter.Value = "Default";
 else
  FieldNameParameter.Value = this.txtFileName.Text.Trim();
  objCom.Parameters.Add(FieldNameParameter);

 SqlParameter pictureParameter = new SqlParameter("@Picture", SqlDbType.Image);
  pictureParameter.Value = content;
 objCom.Parameters.Add(pictureParameter);

   objConn.Open();
  objCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
   objConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    objConn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using Windows form its nice to save picture as image file in database. Following code may help you:                    OpenFileDialog ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofDlg.Filter = JPG|*.jpg|GIF|*.gif|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";
            
            if (DialogResult.OK == ofDlg.ShowDialog())
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofDlg.FileName;
                picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                picturebox.Image = new Bitmap(ofDlg.OpenFile());
                
            }

Answer (score 0):

Check this [ImagesToDatabase](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PictureBoxImage.aspx)

Sample code if you have the path

```
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("your image path");

mySqlCommand = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Image) VALUES(@Image)";//mySqlCommand is a SqlCommand, and @Image is a parameter 
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", img);
mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows form its nice to save picture as image file in database. Following code may help you:

```
 OpenFileDialog ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofDlg.Filter = JPG|*.jpg|GIF|*.gif|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";

        if (DialogResult.OK == ofDlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            textBox1.Text = ofDlg.FileName;
            picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            picturebox.Image = new Bitmap(ofDlg.OpenFile());

        }
```

//while saveing in databasew

db.conopen();
            byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(image);

```
        string query = "update tbl_emp_info set EMP_PHOTO=@image where EMP_ID=@empid";

        cmd=new SqlCommand(query,db.con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",img);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", Emp_id);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How should this code help by saving images to a database? It simply puts a file in a PictureBox, but how does it come into the DB?